# Distinguish sender from receiver with Socket.io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I have built a web application using JavaScript stack (MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS, NodeJS). The registration works, the authentication works, the chat is which is using Socket.io works but I need a way of distinguishing which client is sending and which client is receiving the message in order to perform further functions with the user's data.

P.S. Since this is a project that I can not publish there are no code snippets in my post, hopefully it is alright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate design will depend on what you are trying to achieve. Is is "a one-to-one chat" service or maybe a "one to many broadcast". Is the service anonymous? How do you want users find each other? How secure does it need to be?

As a starting point I would assign a unique identifier (UID) to each connection (client). This will allow the server to direct traffic by creating "conversation" pairings or perhaps a list of listeners (subscribers) and writers (publishers).

A connected user could then enter the UID of a second connected user and your service can post messages back and forth using the uid pairing.

conversation(user123,user0987)
  user123 send to user0987
  user0987 send to user123

or go bulletin board/chat room style:

create a "board" - just a destination that is a list of all text sent
 user123 "joins" board "MiscTalk"
 user0987 "joins board "MiscTalk"

each sends text to the server, server adds that text to the board and each client polls the board for changes.

Every Socket can send or recieve, your program must track "who" is connected on a socket and direct traffic between them.

Answer (score 0):

I think a fine way to handle the clients is creating a Handler class, a Client object and create a clientList in the handler, this way is easier to distinguish the clients. Some months ago I built a simple [open source one-to-one random chat using socket.io](https://github.com/gnuns/omigo), and here are the [handler](https://github.com/gnuns/omigo/blob/master/server/chat/handler.js) and the [client class](https://github.com/gnuns/omigo/blob/master/server/chat/handler.js).

I hope this example can help you.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Create a global server variable and bind connections property to it and whenever the authentication is true ,store socket_id against the id(user_id etc) which you get after decoding your token.

```
global.server=http.createServer(app);
server.connections={};
```

If server.connection hasOwnProperty(id) then use socket emit to send your message ,
else store the socket_id against your id and then send your message.
In this way you just need to know the unique token of the target user to send the message.
2.) You can also use the concept of room 
If authentication is true use 
    `socket.room=id ; socket.join(id)`
when sending message use `client.in(id).emit("YOUR-EVENT-NAME",message)`

Note: Make your own flow , this is just an overview of what I have implemented in the past.You should consider using Redis for storing socket_ids.